# Как подключить библиотеку, состоящую из .h и .cpp

Tags: c++, lib, visual-studio-2019

Нужно подключить библиотеку Anglib.
При скачивании в архиве лежат файлы *.h и *.cpp. При подключении просто заголовочных файлов в проект выдаётся ошибка : неразрешённый элемент.
Что с этим делать?
Где-то видел, что для решения данной проблемы нужно прописать

> pragma comment(lib, "libname.lib")

Но где мне взять этот .lib файл?

Comment: Собрать из исходников этой библиотеки.

Comment: *"в архиве лежат файлы *.h и *.cpp"* А больше там ничего не лежит? Какой-нибудь `Makefile`, `CMakeLists.txt`?..

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, нет, в документации сказано, если я правильно понял, что это для того, чтобы можно было использовать библиотеку в любом компиляторе

Comment: Тогда Alex F все правильно говорит.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, это делается обычными #include-ами?

Comment: Нет, это вообще не кодом делается, а мышкой. Но как именно - не знаю, VS не пользуюсь.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, спасибо за наводку, пойду пробовать

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло включение .сpp и .h файлов в структуру своей программы: в файлы заголовка и исходные файлы.